# nops in superscalar MIPS pipeline

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture

Full disclosure: this is related to a homework question, but is not itself a homework question (if that makes sense).

Let's say I had the following MIPS code:

```
100 addi $1, $0, 1
104 nop
108 addi $2, $0, 2
112 addi $3, $0, 3
```

and I was running it on a superscalar datapath that loads two instructions each cycle. Based on what I know about superscalar pipelines, I would say that in cycle one the processor will fetch instructions 100 and 104.

I would also say that at some point before 100/104 finished executing, the CPU would fetch instructions 108 and 112. Now, if instruction 104 were something other than `nop`, I would say that this would happen in cycle 2 (leaving aside complexities like stalling). However, the fact that it IS a `nop` is making me pause.

I have two questions:

1. Am I correct that the processor will fetch both 100 and 104 in the same cycle? In other words, does a superscalar processor typically have any special handling around fetching `nop` instructions?
2. Assuming my assumption is correct: will instructions 108 and 112 be fetched in cycle 2, or cycle 3?

I suspect the answer would be cycle 2. Although the intent of `nop` is to delay the execution of the next instruction, it does this by just doing some empty work. My suspicion is that the process will just execute the instruction in parallel with instruction 100, and then fetch instructions 108 and 112 in the following cycle.

Comment: Regular nops (canonically: SLL r0, r0, 0) are mostly just padding (delay slot filling might be considered an exception), **but** MIPS defines *superscalar* nops (SLL r0, r0, 1). "SSNOP is intended for use primarily to allow the programmer control over CP0 hazards by converting instructions into cycles in a superscalar processor." SSNOP does consume an entire execution cycle by itself. Squashing NOPs on *fetch* would not seem practical with an ordinary cache (a trace cache however ...), but filtering them out at *decode* is common practice.

Comment: We're working with a pretty simple model of a processor, and a pared-down MIPS instruction set, so I suspect that the solutions you've mentioned (SSNOP, filtering at decode, etc.) aren't available. Thanks for your help